# How to add numeration to stanzas in poemscol?

Tags: numbering, verse, poetry

I would like to make a critical edition for István Gyöngyösi's poem, Csalárd Cupido (hungarian). I would like to numerate my stanzas and not only my verselines. I couldn't find any option in the poemscol package. Is there any workaround?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,makeidx,times,multicol,geometry}
\usepackage{keyval,ifthen,mparhack,manyfoot,poemscol}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{etex,emarks}
\pagestyle{longpoem}
\explanationsatfoot

\begin{document}

\centertitles\poemtitle{A csalard Cupidónak kegyetlenségét megh ősmerő és annak mérges nyilát kerűlő Tiszta életnek Geniusa}
\sequencetitlefirstline{ELSŐ RÉSZ}
\setverselinemodulo{5}
\begin{poem}
\begin{stanza}
El múlt volt már a’ nyár, a’ tél kővetkezet,\verseline
Zőld őltőzetéből erdő le vetkezet,\verseline\explanatory{Az "őltőzetéből" szóban az é betű tollhibásan lejegyezve.}
Nőstényéről az him madár feletkezet,\verseline
Telelő fészkére a’ Fecske érkezet.\end{stanza}
\begin{stanza}
De ragyagot a’ nap vidám fényességgel,\verseline
Ha fodorodot-is néha a’ viz jéggel,\verseline
Reggel volt az űdő, kedvezet fris éggel,\verseline
Midőn meg indúlok minap ollyan véggel,\end{stanza}
\begin{stanza}
Hogy sétálni mennyek, búmat felejteni,\verseline
A melyben nem kis részt kezdettem érzeni,\verseline
Az űdő a’ mint kezd megént térengeni,\verseline
Mihez kellyen nyúlni, s-mit lesz job kezdeni.\end{stanza}
\end{poem}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Poemscol doesn't at the moment have that functionality, but it would not be hard to add. If you could give me some sense of exactly how you would like a marginal stanza number to look (which margin? aligned with verse numbers or offset from them? bold or plain, and so on), I can pull together a new command for you. (I am the author of poemscol)
John Burt

Answer (score 0):

The new command announced by John Burt has been added. Just add `\setverselinemodulo{[your modulo]}` your file will work. Just replace `[your modulo]` with whatever you want it to be.

I added this for anyone searching for this in the future.